# Angular Material Expansion Panel turns all embedded tags into block tags?

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I have document that looks like this:

```
 <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        How To:
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-description class="help-text">

                    Start here to prepare a <i>Connector</i> to link your contract:<br>
                </mat-panel-description>
             </mat-expansion-panel>
          </mat-accordion>
```

What gets render is something like:

```
Start here to prepare a 
Connector
to link your contract.
```

It does the same thing with  tags,  etc.  I can prevent the behavior by adding: `.mat-panel-description i { white-space: nowrap }` in the .css, but seems like there ought to be a way to prevent conversion of inline tags into block tags by the mat-panel-description tag.

}`

Comment: try to wrap it inside a p or div and apply your class on it. Be careful with material components, very often they have their own display settings. Like a display: flex, flex-direction: column would explain what happens to your contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked default styles in mat-expansion-panel-content, and there is

```
.mat-expansion-panel-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

So basicaly wrapping your content inside a "div" will prevent that behavior.